# In node.js res.send returns nothing

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the latest version of **Node.js** with version **6.10.0** and **npm** version is **3.10.10** using express framework, just writing a sample api to send the text "Hello World". I tested it in postman and it doesn't return any data. When I use `console.log`, it displays the data on command prompt.

**Code:**

```
app.get('/api/hello',function(req,res){
    console.log("hello world") 
    res.send("hello world")
 res.status(200).send("hello world")  // it is also not working
})
```

Please help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: That's odd, I tried your code example in a very basic Express app, and it worked. For what it's worth, you don't need to use *status(200)*, because that's the default response code if none is specified. Do you see "hello world" when you just call your URL in a browser, instead of using Postman?

Comment: yes I just checked it in browser instead of postman the page is loading always.

Comment: then please post all of your code, not just the *app.get* call, that is obviously not the problem

Comment: Are you sure Postman is making a `GET` request and not a `POST` request?

Comment: I am using get only.

Comment: Please help me, I am using the windows 10 is there any issue in it.

Comment: this is my code :var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
console.log("hello")
  res.send("hello world")
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})